# no changes in menu items after updating this code trying to remove the some of them

Tags: drop-down-menu, odoo, menuitem, odoo-15, odoo-view

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSZ0r.png) highlighted are the submenu item i want to hide in a custom module.
here are some changes that i have done on backend side but it does not effect the UI side
[adding menu in static please click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1kgZ.png)

i have added in manifest also here is my manifest file
[manifest file for module please click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFB5z.png)

here is my js code file where i'm trying to remove the following menu items [js code file for removing the menu item please click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z18Lo.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the menu items from the registry

***Example:***

```js
/** @odoo-module **/
import { registry } from "@web/core/registry";
import "@web/webclient/user_menu/user_menu_items";

const user_menuitems = registry.category("user_menuitems");
user_menuitems.remove('documentation');
user_menuitems.remove('support');
user_menuitems.remove('log_out');
```

Add the js file to the `assets` entry in the `__manifest__.py` file:

```py
'assets': {
    'web.assets_backend': [
        "MODULE_NAME/static/src/js/user_menu.js",
     ],
},
```

Comment: i have to add this in  .js file to hide ?

Comment: You need to add it under `web.assets_backend` in the `__manifest__.py` file, check my update

Comment: i have added the above as you mentioned but still didn't work on my side after upgrading the module.

Comment: Try importing `user_menu_items` directly. Tested, and it works.

Comment: Importing `user_menu_items.js` is necessary to ensure that actions are already loaded before attempting to delete them.

Comment: tried the modified code in my odoo v 15 sorry it's not working

Comment: Please check the developer console for any error

Comment: it does not showing any error while updating the module but also not reflecting any changes on UI side

Comment: Please update your question and indicate what you've tried so far.

Comment: The file path in the manifest should be `customize_knk/static/src/js/menu.js`

Comment: actually I'm using online server so maybe there are some difference in path of file{like registry and user_menu file} that we have been importing because when i have checked the web module on server it was different one that i have in local. and one more thing i could not find user_menu_item.js  there was just menu_items.js so this js did not work there i also make changes in path of importing file also.

Comment: this kind of js was in meu_item.js 
  
    /**
     * @private
     */
    _onMenuShortcuts: function() {
        new Dialog(this, {
            size: 'large',
            dialogClass: 'o_act_window',
            title: _t("Keyboard Shortcuts"),
            $content: $(QWeb.render("UserMenu.shortcuts"))
        }).open();
    },
});

return UserMenu;

Comment: This answer was tested on Odoo 15 community edition

Comment: yes but I'm using odoo v15 enterprise edition.

Comment: You should mention it

Comment: admitted that was my mistake

Comment: The attached screenshot appears to be from the Community Edition.

Comment: yes it was because i work on lcoal host in community addition and then push the changes online on enterprise but i found that both are totally different.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem was I was using the enterprise edition so because of that the above method was not working So, I have find out the way to hide these menu items by using the JavaScript
> here is command you can add in JavaScript of your module to hide these menu items you can also verify by directly by using developer mode and in console use the below commands(jQuery) to hide the menu items.

```
  $("a[data-menu='documentation']").remove();
  $("a[data-menu='account']").remove();
  $("a[data-menu='support']").remove();
```

Please make sure you document is loaded completely and then after fully loading these commands should be executed to hide these menu items other wise it will not work.